# Generating unique ID tags in ui:include resource

Tags: jsf-2

I am building a page that will have multiple instances of a tag such as the following.

```
<ui:include id="foo" src="images/something.svg" />
```

The Faces Servlet passes through the svg file to the browser without any processing other than EL expressions it finds, which is fine.  The problem is that the id tags in the include file are static, so multiple includes of that file will generate non-unique ID tags.

What I want to do is something like what **h:form** does, where the ID of the **ui:include** tag is prepended to the IDs of the elements in the included file.  Then I could unambiguously address everything.

Is there an accepted "best practice" way of doing this?

UPDATE:  perhaps I should augment this question with a follow up, which is do I need to do this in the first place?  My objective is to uniquely address the tags in each of the included copies of the svg document, of which there can be any number.   I have jQuery available since it is pulled in by Primefaces anyway.

So if I have a JSF file like this:

```
<ui:include id="foo" src="images/something.svg" />
<ui:include id="bar" src="images/something.svg" />
```

And inside the something.svg file I have a tag

```
<rect id="blink" ... />
```

In the javascript on the page, I want to be able to get a pointer to **foo:blink** or **bar:blink**.  I suppose I could use XPath expressions but I understood those are kind of slow.  I can't imagine the guys who invented the **ui:include** tag haven't thought about how to deal with this so I am assuming I missed something obvious.

Comment: To be clear, the `something.svg` is thus *actually* a Facelet file?

Comment: No, it is just an svg document starting with (after headers) an svg tag.  This works very well in HTML 5 for inserting dynamic and interactive documents into a page, and JSF has no problem in generating it.   The thing is the Faces servlet doesn't process any ID tags except for those in UIComponents, and nothing in the svg file is a JSF-defined tag.

Comment: But you mentioned that it processes EL expressions in it? It would then in theory be possible to bring in JSF components or even make it just a composite component which would already get an autogenerated ID.

Comment: The Faces servlet does indeed find and process EL expressions in the included SVG file.  For example you can do <rect id="#{bean.idGenerator}" .. /> and generate unique IDs that way.  The problem with this approach is that it makes the SVG file uneditable with graphics tools like inkscape.    Other than that the Faces servlet passes through everything in the SVG file without interpretation except (i assume) if it finds a tag in a namespace it knows such as f: h: or ui:.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as [`<ui:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/param.html).

```
<ui:include src="images/something.svg">
    <ui:param name="id" value="foo" />
</ui:include>
<ui:include src="images/something.svg">
    <ui:param name="id" value="bar" />
</ui:include>
```

You can reference it by the param name `#{id}` in EL of the included file. E.g.

```
<rect id="#{id}_blink" ... />
```

Comment: I like it.  I didn't know you could use a **ui:param** that way.   It is not my ideal solution because I was trying to avoid putting things in the svg source file that would confuse an editor like Inkscape.  However I just tried it and Inkscape doesn't seem to mind having an EL expression in the ID tags.   So I will go with this unless something better comes up.   I was afraid I would have to write a filter or something.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw thanks for sharing your experience that including SVG files with EL expressions like that works just fine. I just learnt something new :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

`<f:subview id="uniqueXXX">`

see also [this example](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_subview.html):